# store depth in recursion bash

Tags: bash, recursion, depth

I need to travel through directories to certain depth(parameter2, default = 3) starting in a certain dir(parameter1). If i stumble upon a file i also need to print the depth of the file from the starting point. I'm doing this with recursion but i don't know **how to stop looking at certain depth and how to print it**

my code so far:

```
function tree(){
    for path in "{$1}/*"        
        if [ -d "$path"]; then
            printf "%5s %s" DIR $path #and also depth           
            tree "$path"
        else [ -f "$path"]; then
            printf "%5s %s" File $path #and also depth              
        fi
        done
}
```

If possible without "find" please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass current depth as a parameter:

```
function tree(){
    local max_depth=$2
    if [ -n "$max_depth" ]; then
        max_depth=3
    fi
    tree_helper $1 0 $max_depth
}

function tree_helper() {
    local current_depth=$2
    local max_depth=$3
    for path in "{$1}/*"        
        if [ -d "$path"]; then
            printf "%5s %s %d" DIR $path $current_depth #and also depth           
            if [ $current_depth -lt $max_depth ]; then
                tree_helper "$path" $((current_depth+1)) $max_depth
            fi
        else [ -f "$path"]; then
            printf "%5s %s" File $path $current_depth
        fi
        done
}
```

You can also use `find` with `-maxdepth` option:

Write a file `print_depth.sh` which contains:

```
input=$1
slashes=$(echo $input | awk -F/ '{print NF}')
echo $input $((slashes-1))
```

Then simply do:

```
 chmod +x print_depth.sh
 find . -maxdepth 3 -exec ./print_depth.sh {} \;
```